# How to group random numbers in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, grouping, histogram

If I run the code `rand(4,4)` then that will give me a 4x4 matrix with random numbers between 0 and 1. How do I then get Matlab to group these data into groups like `0 - 0.09, 0.1 - 0.19, 0.2, 0.29,` etc, which I can then plot in a histogram?

What I have done, is created an M-file that will give me a randomly generated number. I then want to run the file 100 times and get 100 different random numbers and then group them like this, so if I understand the basics, then I can apply it to my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `histc` can help you.

```
>> v = rand( 1, 100 ); % generate 100 RV at once (matlab is all about vectorization)
>> edges = 0:.1:1; % edges of histogram bins
>> counts = histc( v, edges );
>> bar( counts );
```